# How to set image to UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I set image to `UIImage` object.
For example:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"]];
```

My `UIImage` object is declared in `.h` file and allocated in `init` method, I need to set image in `viewDidLoad` method.
Any ideas?

Comment: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed@"anyImageName"];

Comment: you can **declare** something in interfaces (what you call .h file), but not create it there.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"];
```

> **[imageNamed:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)**
>       Returns the image object associated with the specified filename.
>
> ```
>     + (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
> ```
>
> Parameters
>   **name**
>       The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the
>   application’s main bundle.
>   **Return Value**
>       The image object for the specified file, or nil if the method could not find the specified image.
>
> **Discussion**
>       This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.

Comment: object is created in .h file and allocated in init method, I need set image in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: so create a property and assign it to it

Comment: no, but if you want to know about properties, you should ask a new question and not try to deal with it in comments to an answer to an questions about how to create a UIImage with an image file.

Answer (score 11):

Create a UIImageView and add UIImage to it:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image Name"]] ;
```

Then add it to your view:

```
[self.view addSubView: imageView];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just Follow This**

```
UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400)];
[imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"]];
[imgview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.view addSubview:imgview];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on this line:

```
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"anyImageName"]];
```

It should be:

```
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"]];
```

Comment: It is wrong. because an UIImage have not any method like setImage: .

Comment: in  this code right but one mistake also solve out Mr.jeremy .. Thank u sir share your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed@"aImageName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

may be:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

and when you want to change the image:

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfPng.png"];
```

but the object wasn't in the same place in the memory, but if you use the pointer, the same pointer will be point to the last image loaded.

Comment: and this is call memory leak :)

Comment: Yes sure, but before the reassigned the new image, you made a [img released]. I don't put it here, because it's the base of Objective-C...

Comment: well even in non-ARC `-released` will yield a selector not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Like vikingosgundo said, but keep in mind that if you use `[UIImage imageNamed:image]` then the image is cached and eats away memory. So unless you plan on using the same image in many places, you should load the image, with `imageWithContentsOfFile:` and `imageWithData:`

This will save you significant memory and speeds up your app.

Answer (score 0):

First declare UIImageView and give it frame

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 10.0f, 15.0f, 40.0f,40.0f )];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comments_profile_image.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview: imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Image in UIImage object eiter of the following way:

1. `UIImage *imageObject = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageFileName"];`
   but by initializing `UIImage` Object like this, the image is always stored in cache memory even you make it `nil` like `imageObject=nil;`

Its better to follow this:

1. `NSString *imageFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageFilename" ofType:@"imageFile_Extension"];`

   ```
   UIImage *imageObject = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
   ```

EXAMPLE:  `NSString *imageFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"png"];`

```
UIImage *imageObject = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this line

```
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"]];
```

with following line

```
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImageName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alloc UIImage, this is impossible.
Proper code with UIImageView allocate:

```
UIImageView *_image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"]] ;
```

Draw image:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, _image.image.CGImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to 100% work....

```
UIImageView * imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,100, 80, 80)];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"];
[self.view  addSubview:imageview];
```